# How to insert Current time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write a mysql query to insert the current time and a future time?

The future time should be 5 minutes later than the current time.

I have this:

```
insert into ab(id, time, future_time) VALUES (1, 'NOW()', NOW());
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried 'new Date() ' ?

Comment: is this mySql command

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
insert into ab(id, time, future_time) VALUES (1, now(), date_add(now(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE));
```

I do not have MySql here, so I cannot verify it but you can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) for details.

Answer (score 1):

`CURTIME()` it will return current time. see here for doc [Mysql Date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
insert into ab(id, time, future_time) VALUES (1, CURTIME(), DATE_ADD(CURTIME(),INTERVAL 5 MINUTE));
```

you will get current time

```
mysql> SELECT CURTIME();
        -> '23:50:26
```

'

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() command.
see here  [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html](http://5%20MINUTE)

insert into ab(id, time, future_time) VALUES (1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + 5 MINUTE);